# Custom field widget that displays a button with JS action and a hidden textbox

Tags: entities

I have no background in working with the Drupal API, so answers will have to explain it like I'm a child.

I am trying to create a custom field module. The widget should show a button with JS onClick action that opens an external form. The user selects through a series of prompts and the external form returns XML to the page that should be stored in a hidden XML field (I'm using the XML Field module). The XML is never shown to the user, but instead powers a JS script on node view.

The formatter for the field should deliver the content of the XML field as a JS variable and not display anything on the page.

I've read through the Drupal API documentation and several tutorials on building custom fields. However, these all assume a working knowledge of the Field API, which I do not possess.

Is this possible in a field module, or should I be looking at a different way of implementing this?

I'm using Drupal 7 and the external form is a client metadata requirement I have no control over.

Comment: This is possible with the field module. It sounds like it may also be possible with a HOOK_form_alter. There are probably countless other ways this could be done. This is not the place to find full tutorials though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome here. You're question is complicated with many steps some involving the Drupal API and others involving Javascript and Ajax. Your question is specific to your needs, so you'll likely not find a module that does exactly what you're asking for out of the box.

You're correct that the Drupal API should be able to do this -- but by asking people to show you how to do like your 5; is basically asking someone to do your homework for you. I can outline the tools you'll need. It's up to you to come to a working solution.

1st off -- outline your code outside of the Drupal API and simply thing "how would this form work in psuedocode" using say PHP and JS; building those steps will take you a long way.

Drupal Resources to help you:

- [The Field API Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/group/field/7) pages.
- [The Official Field API Tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/707832), which links some 3rd party tutorials as well.
- If the above 2 resources aren't enough to understand what the Field API does look at the [Examples module for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples).
- It sounded like you wanted AJAX in your form. Read up on the [Drupal Javascript API Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/751744), specifically the [Ajax Forms](https://www.drupal.org/node/752056) section, and again if that's not enough look at the Examples module, or google "drupal jquery form" as while Drupal has it's own JS API, Drupal *bundles* jQuery so you could try to just use jQuery to fulfill your needs mostly without the field api explicitly.

  - what do I mean by this? Here is a [jquery autocomplete tutorial](http://serho.ru/notes/raznoe/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-v-forme-drupal-7) which uses a text field "in" drupal but is simply using jquery's native autocomplete functions. I used Google Translate for that page and View Source in my browser to fill in the tutorial gaps -- to re-engineer this on a site I have.

Lastly, either route you'll take you will likely be integrating with an existing Node form. You probably want to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to inject your custom business logic into the existing Drupal functionality.

Comment: The API tutorial helped, but I had to work my way through the building a module tutorial to really understand how things work. Thanks for the push in the right direction!